# How to add border at the bottom of a table row which is broken due to page break

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a dynamically generated HTML which has content that might run across pages.

I need to test this in IE6.

When there is a table that runs to multiple pages, in Print preview of IE, the bottom border of the last row is not shown in each broken page.
The bottom border appears only in the last page or where the table is closing.

Since IE6 does not support page-break-inside:avoid, there is NO clear way of drawing a border thru HTML

I need to know if jquery can be used in such scenario

Comment: No. Use PDF if you want to control printing

Comment: @Imran yes I have a scenario where client insists on IE6. I know its long back in history but what else to do :(

Comment: @user4310642 ...introduce your client to all of the security holes they are allowing by using such an old browser....or jump on board and grab an abacus to tally your consultant fees

Comment: @user4310642 Try to convince him that support for IE6 is time consuming & there is no one uses for it, Share this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp), You can also create a page for old IE which tells users the following: `This browser is not supported please download [modern browser](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp).`

Comment: Did you try to put the bottom border on the table cells instead of table rows? You'd obviously also have to remove any padding or spacing in between the cells and rows.

Comment: Thanks Imran for the link